# How cy.click on all buttons starting from 2nd element in Cypress?

Tags: cypress

How can I click on all the the buttons but starting from the 2nd element?
Here is my code:

```
it('Click menu buttons one by one', function () {

    cy.visit('http://localhost:25000/', { timeout: 300000 })
    cy.wait(10000)
    cy.get('.dijitReset.dijitInline.dijitMenuItemLabel.dijitMenuItem', { timeout: 200000}) .click({multiple: true }) 
    cy.waitSomeTime(10000)

})
```

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your html DOM, then I would be able to help you with exact code. if not, you can use `each()` or `eq()` to achieve this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `each()`:

```js
cy
  .get('.dijitReset.dijitInline.dijitMenuItemLabel.dijitMenuItem')
  .each(($btn, index) => {
    if (index >= 1) cy.wrap($btn).click();
});
```

More examples could be found in the doc [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/each.html).

Comment: This approach is briliant. I would have used `.then()` and a for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Something new I saw today in a Cypress internal test

```js
cy.get('.dijitReset.dijitInline.dijitMenuItemLabel.dijitMenuItem')
  .invoke('slice', 1)  // take from 2nd onwards
  .click({multiple: true})
```

Ref: [jQuery .slice()](https://api.jquery.com/slice/)

> Reduce the set of matched elements to a subset specified by a range of indices